# Maven - several modules for one package

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a web app that I would like to split into three pieces. I noticed it has two completely distinct functionalities, but the core architecture (libs used in presentation layer, Spring container, DAO etc.) is shared.

One piece would be the "master", with full vertical stack from presentation through DAO, but only for what's common for all "subprojects".

The other two modules would be the "subprojects" themselves.

Now the question is: Is it possible to get Maven to treat all 3 pieces (modules?) as one, so that they would be built and most importantly packaged together? I need the final result to be a single war with directory tree similar to:

```
war
 + WEB-INF
   + classes
     + subproject1
     + subproject2
 + view-shared
   + css
     + ...
   + js
     + ...
 + subproject1
   + myPage.jsp
 + subproject2
   + anotherPage.jsp
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the Maven assembly plugin.

Another solution is to have:

- A `common` project (packaging `jar`)
- A `subproject1` (packaging `war`) that has `common` as dependency.
- A `subproject2` (packaging `war`) that has `common` as dependency.
- Finally, a `web` project (packaging `war`) that has both `subproject1` and `subproject2` as dependencies.

When Maven will build the `web` project, it will first unzip both `subproject1` and `subproject2` wars in the `web/target` directory, and then copy the content of the `web` project itself in this `target` directory.

This means that if a file exists in `subproject1` and in `web` projects, then the file hosted by `web` will erase the one hosted by `subproject1` in the final WAR file.

You can find more information about [Maven WAR overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Build separate maven modules for all three, plus a forth module that depends on the other modules and uses the assembly plugin to build the structure you need.